# Prestashop 1.6 - php into admin override tpl

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

Just wanted to include a custom php file into an override template I've made but when I use:

```
{php} include('custom_code.php'); {/php}
```

or:

```
{include_php file='../../../../../../panel/update.php'}
```

The page crashes. Prestashop is so hard to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue creating a plugin for smarty in the directory

```
/tools/smarty/plugins
```

with the file name

```
function.update_customer.php
```

. then i pute the code in my template .tpl with this shortcode hook

```
{update_customer}
```

.
Hope that helps in the future...

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are following to include the PHP file is absolutely wrong, you should include the file in the Class file responsible for rendering the TPL file.

Once you do that you can write the business logic in the class file and then pass the required data to TPL file using the following code:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('any_var', $any_value);
```

By using this you can get the data in your Smarty file and use the same accordingly.